# Passing a class pointer to a function and then access members when class is in scope

Tags: c++

Basically the class constructors have been set up already and are working correctly based on some previous tests. Now I need to create a class pointer object in main pass that to a function and then inside that function call another function which will create an instance of the Box class with a specific name and while the class is in scope print out that boxes name.

This code is only designed based on some restrictions so that's why it is not as clean or simple as it probably could be. I've tried lots of different things but none of it seems to make any sense to me. I keep getting an access violation:

```
void objCreateTmp(char *n)
{
   //cout<<"HERE";      
   Box tmp(n);
   cout<<"HERE"; 
   //tmp.name_set(n);
   tmp.name_print();
}

void objCreateKeep(Box *p, char *n)
{
  objCreateTmp(n);
}


int main()
{   

    Box *pp = new Box;
    objCreateKeep(pp,"Blue Box");
    objCreateKeep(pp,"Red Box");
    objCreateKeep(pp,"Orange Box");


    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, so here is everything to do with accessing, getting,setting the name member of the `Box` class:

```
void Box::pri_setname(char *n)
{
   strcpy(name,n);  
}
//Set the name of Box()
void Box::name_set(char *n)
{
    name = new char[30];
    strcpy(name,n);
    pri_setname(name);
}

 class Box{

  //Private data members
  private:
  char *name;
  void pri_setname(char *n);

  public:
  //Public constructors and deconstructor
  Box(char *);
  ~Box();
  //Public function prototypes
  void name_set(char *n);
  void name_print();

};
```

Comment: This code block appears to be fine. What is the function definiton for `Box::name_print()` ?

Comment: void Box::name_set(char *n)

Comment: I asked `name_print()`

Comment: Also, which line gives you an access violation ?

Comment: I get an access violation right at Box tmp(n);

Comment: Is `name_set` a private function ? Is `name_print` a private function ?

Comment: Neither of them are private

Comment: Is your overloaded constructor private by any chance ? Add the definition of the relevant constructor to the question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh. My fault. I thought access violation != Segmentation Fault. I mostly work in C hence I thought access violation was because of incorrect access modifiers. Also, OP doesnt explicitly mention whether its a runtime issue or not.

Comment: My overloaded constructor is public. Only private function member is the pri_setname which basically should just take the n pointer that is accessed by any of the functions and copies it over to the private data member name

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! I think i can figure it out now that you pointed that out.